# Windows Forms graphics blink

Tags: winforms, graphic, blink

I have a Windows Forms application, borderstyle=none, own background image, when i start application window show partly and fill when every control will paint, how to do that form will showed when all controls will be painted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call the **Invalidate** method.